# SHA256withRSA Signature Verification in nodejs returning false every time

Tags: javascript, node.js, rsa, sha256, cryptojs

I am trying to verify signature added to a XML as per the instructions on the link below. It is returning false. I tried some code in Java too but will prefer NodeJS to work. Any other module recommendation is also welcome.

[Instructions on the website for Validation](https://uidai.gov.in/authentication/authentication-devices-documents/aadhaar-paperless-offline-e-kyc-verification.html)

**Steps to validate signature :**

1. Read the entire XML and separate the s="xxxx" tag from it.
2. Use a signature validation algorithm leveraging "SHA256withRSA" based hashing and encryption technique
3. Signature value present in "s" tag, remaining XML (without "s" tag) and UIDAI public key (available here.) is to be fed to the algorithm to validate digital signature.
4. Sample code snippets provided here.

**Please find below my code: [using NodeJS Crypto module]**

```js
var crypto = require('crypto');
let fs = require('fs');

const CERT = '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n' +
    'MIIDhTCCAm2gAwIBAgIEYhPgKjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBrMQswCQYDVQQGEwJJ\n' +
    'TjESMBAGA1UECBMJS2FybmF0YWthMRIwEAYDVQQHEwlCYW5nYWxvcmUxEDAOBgNV\n' +
    'BAoTB2hjbC1hdWExEDAOBgNVBAsTB2hjbC1hdWExEDAOBgNVBAMTB2hjbC1hdWEw\n' +
    'HhcNMTgwMTAzMTMyNTQ5WhcNMTkwMTAzMTMyNTQ5WjBrMQswCQYDVQQGEwJJTjES\n' +
    'MBAGA1UECBMJS2FybmF0YWthMRIwEAYDVQQHEwlCYW5nYWxvcmUxEDAOBgNVBAoT\n' +
    'B2hjbC1hdWExEDAOBgNVBAsTB2hjbC1hdWExEDAOBgNVBAMTB2hjbC1hdWEwggEi\n' +
    'MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4IBDwAwggEKAoIBAQCBgQBr8wRk6QbtUsq6YvxEnY22\n' +
    'wr9mW62qVXpaWLVHYcbuVtBALf5LXFK3WnLAY15xKKQ9m9WZa8w2ZMpo20UePoLM\n' +
    'QSda0Gk4gFhe0Dl+czlNSLMnMlYc4qWrPrpUlFTi7KZKDLKrQKpQjacY/OKqUVYj\n' +
    '98IPsbp/IivpSvkwIaS3J1cyORNYCdtDLhpAbUUX0rCrJJXl3245BCJ/3jbtpQ+F\n' +
    '7Cc81sBVYT31b+L04G3h5Ih3hsFg24xrJES1WglsBZBNAbFnSE2CjMfNLUIikZjz\n' +
    'RfcQ5MZgU2/mGjlgGrLV/GX+8yQ0VRryWEmTNDDb0skGkY3ZQafgOHa0Vxg9AgMB\n' +
    'AAGjMTAvMA4GA1UdDwEB/wQEAwIHgDAdBgNVHQ4EFgQUagX6xg6PhyaYYI6cjAip\n' +
    'lBHT5S8wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQADggEBAG1z3DQoXjo9u+QfflnymFvcwRcc+vQ1\n' +
    'xE/5n85G5Gl6PD1fw0HSOOEMbt2obx/L367UVX0+bSi0eG7lFADSfL9G5B+RN+wP\n' +
    '0ItLNoG8uc9F0SbQMUw21WLEnkQydjjg+7wp4PXPxyEtaRNYLjus7UbU/xnHTf6W\n' +
    'ltI9ngHEr1w69H9d17KiQsFBeGjg0qfH9CGhhKT2q0ETKWQSPI3fwCx3Z4AmS2nZ\n' +
    'tog4WzWZlOMLHoPeYsFGv4gTgzbRWX0jc6HZ0057TDo+XWErcSuxBSGX8jEGLfp2\n' +
    'tW4LOAE3autC9HsG4OQBiR+nEbMEHbm3Pv8meRvfgTV6P6qQiICeMaI=\n' +
    '-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n';

verifier = crypto.createVerify('sha256WithRSAEncryption');
verifier.update('<OKV v="1" n="Ravi Krishna Nalagatla" i="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" d="10121993" e="ac342bb947d5aa49847a0a05f87c388759a6cb156e04eac6ae995e9dca5ba1d9" m="254618fd06a2e7308247c7f0fb547f58174ab3b99e7b042d6705a5457235f32a" g="male" a="S/O Narasimham, 45, 74, 4, 7, Secunderabad, Hyderabad, Andhra Pradesh - 500003" r="328020181115111938451"/>'); //XML without S attribute
const signature ="VFKxVswVqlPDYOnp7rHUTtLVR3/NQN/p1dI61s1KSy102OgRI5YbXLj9Ng8Cy1fo6a5S62d0NldczYpztM5/E8Z6YUhtknhdVLD24fPijrFoUEqVC2S2fr8FUsCdVXNJEYd2v+UZ2grGYYi68rslaLO7z8SChoedsupRj2F1mwRyrof4u6kdAK5BxvubHPlEZ34Gv3ivuyJnJAKEyDkoymlm2GOAnaLUIxN5vdyBANZMOv9geH2poFOdUGVvOjDbpTPBF3Y5ADosYQYoErsONJ68x3iJsiZcG6dw1gPIW5J3B+X2vgXtFbF9xjFs7rZV9jk7Q8bJos5W8JuVjwV37g=="; //value of S attribute

var result = verifier.verify(CERT, signature);

console.log(result, 'result'); // **It is returning false always**.
```

Comment: Sample data to verify is available on the link https://uidai.gov.in/authentication/developer-section/tutorial-section.html#tab3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the certificate in your sample code and the certificate to be used are different. Try using below certificate I found in the URL you shared.

https://uidai.gov.in/images/okyc-publickey.cer

Also, the sample data seems invalid. I tried it on Live data XML(can't share here) with the certificate. It returned me true after two changes:

1. One extra space needs to be removed from XML after the `s` element is removed.
2. Pass Signature as a buffer with base64 decoding.

```
const signature = new Buffer("hchpGi49Pm8z5KDAnnmqHEUzVSE1ovQsWzhjx0RnRrh33H0oHYOpw1vQ9HuQwOtjtoNtKrpU+2ikduVkxw1DXI0jVnNsw6F0vQeELBOBw2qQ4QdJ0Zwx0A3+nBF0zHVaJE/fUhIhzLjGsfoGF5ohEotkQxtFcP5lrlfQDUj69LEu2RpcW7kBYH9PAQCGcs0b5hhcdP0eR6F2gYhi7dV5ieDL1c6Ta6NW1HroWEQI0Lk0NmeXuh2efzJfk4S8uc0MrhBUzLAa4N9WDUyegYcfTKJHtt6vpxVIyqs3ObQn9osHj9WmDMWVZiJvRz7tMaQdDU6gh74p734UPjk5CioUnw==", "base64");
```